# Will the Honda CG 125 engine be able to lift a 200kg weight at 2100 RPM?

Tags: experimental-aircraft

[image]

I found a Rotex company engine with a maximum RPM of 5800. However, company allows 70%  mean 4000 RPM, so I'm sure that 2100 RPM will be enough for lifting or take off and be able to climb. I have seen a lot of video clips on YouTube of bike-engined aircraft flying, but in all videos nobody shown bike engine, so I'm also doubtful that some of the videos real. Will the Honda CG 125 engine be able to climb with 200 kg weight or not?

Comment: So you see youtube videos that shows bike engined planes, and you don't think CG125 engine is powerful enough, then you think the video is fake? So the logic is youtubers must not have used any bike engine other than CG125?

Comment: Good evening here Karachi Pakistan welcome my friend. But here Karachi Pakistan I watched some bike engine ( rickshaw) , pulling seven people's with 50Km speed. I shocked.